# Mouseless: Restore Hipchat's Windows client?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, mouseless, window-restore

Using only my keyboard, how can I bring to the forefront the Hipchat Windows client that has been minimized to the notification area?

Answer (score 1):

Windows+B, arrows keys, Enter

The arrow keys step can be omitted if you arrange your notification area icons such that Hipchat is always leftmost.